# Why does java doesn't let me do 1/n?

Tags: java

:)
I've been trying to do something like:
`double a = 1/35;` but the result is alway 0.0

I need to do those kind of divitions. What can I do?

Thanks :)

Comment: use `1.0/35;` to perform double division

Comment: Because integer / integer is integer division, which gives an integer result.

Comment: `double a = 1d/35d;`

Comment: for `int n>0`, `(n-1)/n` will always be zero.  So do double `d = 1/35.;` or `d = 1./35;`